# how to find the global peak in image histogram in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, coordinates

For an image where I am finding the horizontal projection, I am plotting those points as a histogram. How can I find the coordinates where the histogram has a global peak? How can I find the coordinates of the peak?

`I = imread('F:\Work parth\sample images\england.tif');
horizontal_projection=sum(bw,2); plot(horizontal_projection);`

Answer (score 2):

Do :

```
Peak_location = find(horizontal_projection(:) == max(horizontal_projection(:));
```

The above answer gives as output the unique peak location (if there is only one), as well as the multiple peak locations if there are many global peaks with the same value.

Comment: Thanks Arturo, this is extremely useful. Could you please tell me as to how I can get the coordinates of the point where there is a peak?

Comment: `[row,col] = find(___)` will do it for you (see [find](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html))